# highcharts not rendering chart inside jquery mobile tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, highcharts

I have jquery mobile website with a few tabs and  i have added a highcharts bar chart...The data is taken from a table.. But the problem is that the chart is not visible in the second tab.

After doing some research i found out that adding `reflow()` will work so i added the below code and still the chart doesnt load

```
 var chart = $("#container_chart").highcharts(); // target the chart itself
chart.reflow() // reflow that chart
```

Below is my full JS code

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).delegate("#property_page", "pagecreate", function() {

          var chart =  $('#container_chart').highcharts({
                data: {
                   table: 'datatable'
                },

                chart: {
                    type: 'column',

                    events: {
                        tooltipRefresh: function(e) {
                          if (!e.target.hoverSeries) return;
                          $('.highcharts-tooltip>path:last-of-type')
                            .css('fill', e.target.hoverSeries.color);
                        }
                      }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Charts'
                },
                credits:false,
                labels: {
                   format: '{value}'
               },
                yAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: false,

                    title: {
                        text: ''
                    }
                },
                xAxis: {
                    gridLineWidth: 1, // New value
                    gridLineColor: '#DCEBEF',
                    lineColor: '#ffffff',
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    crosshair: false,
                    type: 'category',

                    tickmarkPlacement: 'between',

                    plotLines: [{
                        color: '#FF0000', // Red
                        width: 2,
                        value: 5.5 // Position, you'll have to translate this to the values on your x axis
                    }]

                },
                colors: [
                         '#33a9ec',
                         '#ec3342',

                     ],
                legend: {

                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',

                    backgroundColor: null,
                },
                linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 1,
                    y2: 0
               },

                tooltip: {
                    backgroundColor: null,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: null,

                  },
            });

             var chart = $("#container_chart").highcharts(); // target the chart itself
          chart.reflow() // reflow that chart
        });
        </script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="container_chart" class="container_chart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px;"></div>

<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Distribution</th>
            <th>Return</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>2011</th>
            <td>6250</td>
            <td>6250</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2012</th>
            <td>28205</td>
            <td>40000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2013</th>
            <td>26000</td>
            <td>34750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>2014</th>
            <td>32500</td>
            <td>10000</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can also view the page here http://vidznet.com/debug/tabs.html

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You don't load any data to the chart. `data` option requires `data.js` module, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data) :)

Comment: Thanks alot.. It works now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to include `data.js` in order it to work..

Thanks to Paweł Fus